# Problem trying to query several values from a mysql table into php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an HTML page that takes multiple input from the useras a numeric code and then displays output in another php page. The data is retrieved from a database table.

my code is not working, can you please help me figure out why?

**the php code:**

```
$var1 = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI1']}%'";
$var2 = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI2']}%'";
$var3 = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI3']}%'";
$var4 = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI4']}%'";


$sql = "select * from table $var1" ;
$sql .= "select * from table $var2" ;
$sql .= "select * from table $var3" ;
$sql .= "select * from table $var4" ;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql1, $sql2, $sql3, $sql4);
```

Thanks in advance, I appreciate all the help. I'm still new to using php so I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

edit:

the code is now the following:

```
$var1 = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI1']}%' OR CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI2']}%' OR CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI3']}%' OR CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI4']}%' "; 

$sql = "select * from proteinpd $var1;";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
.
.
.


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
```

it is showing me the result of all the table and not only for the codes I have chosen. Why so?

**INPUT FORM:**

```
<form action="output.php" method="POST" >
<table>
        <div>  
            <h2 > AGI </h2> 
           <p><input name="AGI1"type="text"></p>
           <p><input name="AGI2" type="text"></p>
           <p><input name="AGI3" type="text"></p>
           <p><input name="AGI4" type="text"></p>
           <p> <input type="Submit" value="OK"></p>
            
        </div>  
    </form>
```

Database table structure:

[image]

Comment: There are multiple issues:
- You're concatenating sql queries, but there's no separator between them, like ;
- Also the $sql is not used anywhere
- The mysqli_query does seem to have different interface (params) - https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Why not use OR in the where clause?  e.g. "where code like 'aaa' or code like 'bbb' ..."

Comment: thanks for your reply. I edited my code similar to what you told me so now it looks like this:

`$var = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI1']}%' OR CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI2']}%' OR CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI3']}%' OR CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI4']}%' ";

$sql = "select * from table $var;" ;

 $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);`

but now instead of showing me results for this query, it's showing me results from all the table. Any idea why? Thanks :)

Comment: you have single input box field or multiple?

Comment: i have multiple input fields in the HTML page, four input fields.

Comment: so why you make multiple input fields searching for same column `code` ?

Comment: the user inputs different code values, and each code has different values for attributes. For example, if the user inputs code 1 and 2, then i want to display all the relevant information for both codes in a table.

Comment: use `AND` for that.

Comment: `$var = "where CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI1']}%' AND CODE like '%{$_POST['AGI2']}%' ";` try with & let me know.

Comment: hey KUMAR. I tried using `AND` and the result is an empty table. I don't want `AND` but rather `OR`. However the `OR` is giving me the results of all the table which is also what I don't want. I want only the results from what the user inputs. So code 1 or code 2, then I want the information relating to code 1 and the information for code 2.

Comment: @FlexingDuck please show us your table structure & input form also. , so we can help you.

Comment: @KUMAR i updated my post to show the form and the table that takes the input. Thanks.

Comment: @FlexingDuck where is your database table structure?.

Comment: @KUMAR sorry. i just added a screenshot of the table (AGICODE is the same as CODE)

Answer (score 0):

When you are combining your sql queries you need to end each query with a `;`.

```
$sql = "select * from table $var1;" ;
$sql .= "select * from table $var2;" ;
$sql .= "select * from table $var3;" ;
$sql .= "select * from table $var4;" ;
```

See also how to use [mysqli_multi_query](https://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of `mysqli_query`.

See the [Example#1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php) in the official documentation. You should also consider to refactor your code to prevent [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496).

Comment: Don't you realize that such a query just makes no sense for the task?

Comment: Besides, how the OP should refactor the code from your answer, if  mysqli_multi_query **doesn't** support prepared statements? Can't you make your answer more consistent and less self-contradicting?